# Where are Visual Studio Debug Source File Directories Saved?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

When I go to the properties of a solution in Visual Studio, and add a directory `c:\somepath` under: "Common Properties" -> "Debug Source Files", where is that directory recorded?  In what file? I can't find any trace of it in the following files:

```
mylibrary.sln
mylibrary.vcxproj
mylibrary.vcxproj.user
mylibrary.vcxproj.filters
.vs directory
```

Comment: They apear in `C:\path_to_project\project_name\project_name\Debug` for me.

Comment: Thanks, but I that is a directory name.  I'm looking for a specific file which contians `c:\somepath` as a string inside it.  It might be binary.

Comment: @solvingJ it's project relative and settable in the configuration settings for each project

Comment: @Mgetz that's encouraging, but I could not find any such configuration settings for each project.  I found several sources indicating it's "Solution" specific, not "project" specific at all.  Can you provide any specific steps on how to configure it?

Comment: @solvingJ  open the vsproj file with a text editor, you'll see the entry internally

Comment: As I said in my question, I looked in my vcxproj file and found no trace.  I have concluded it's stored in binary format within `.vs/.suo`, because if i delete this file, and re-open the solution, it has forgotten c:\somepath.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, heaven knows why.  There are some strings in there but they are Unicode (UTF-16).  Good question.

Comment: It is in the .vs directory, but the file is hidden.  It is a binary file, its format is not documented and does change between VS versions.  Lots more stuff goes in there, most visibly the tool window arrangement.  Debug state is in general not saved along with the solution and projects, also note the .user file.  There is (brief) documentation about this file here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Interesting, thank you.  I see the logic now.