# step into standard wstdio functions in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, utf-8

I want to find the reason why with the new feature `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8")` the standard function `fgetwc()` can't read `'\u2013'` (EN DASH) from a utf8 text file and instead returns `WEOF`. Maybe find a workaround.

I disabled "Only my code" and enabled symbol downloading for `C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll` that contains `fgetwc`
However, when I try to step into that function it cannot find `fgetwc.cpp`.

These two locations don't contain that file and I can't find any other place:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\crt\src\
```

This is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    wint_t wc; // = L'\u2013';
    FILE* file;
    printf("%s\n", setlocale(LC_ALL, ".utf8"));
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    wc = fgetwc(file);

    // ffff '?' 0 0
    fprintf(stdout, "%04x '%lc' %d %d\n", wc, wc, ferror(file), feof(file));
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `ffff` instead of `2013`. `ferror()` and `feof()` return false.

test.txt:

```
–
```

It's encoded as `E2 80 93`

Comment: Try `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Source\10.0.<build>\ucrt\stdio`.

Comment: @dxiv that worked . Thanks

Comment: For the second part, see if the manifest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65245489/5538420) makes a difference.

Comment: @dxiv do you know how to add a `debug source files` folder globally so other projects have it?

Comment: The [Debug Source Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-source-files-common-properties-solution-property-pages-dialog-box?view=vs-2019) list of directories is set and saved per solution (presumably in the `.vs` subdirectory as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515367/where-are-visual-studio-debug-source-file-directories-saved#comment88044981_50515367)). Don't know offhand where the global defaults come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For reading the UTF-8 file, optionally drop the `setlocale` call, and replace the `fopen` line with:

  ```
  file = fopen("test.txt", "r, ccs=utf-8");
  ```

  The [`fopen` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-160) states:

  > ccs=encoding -- Specifies the encoded character set to use (one of UTF-8, UTF-16LE, or UNICODE) for this file. Leave unspecified if you want ANSI encoding.

  This appears to imply that the `ccs=UTF-8` encoding must be specified explicitly in order to read a file as UTF-8 text.

  Though, on the other hand, "*ANSI*" used to mean either the active codepage, or the system default locale. With the recent support in Windows 10 1903 and later for UTF-8 as an active codepage, it would be expected that "*ANSI encoding*" be the same as "*UTF-8 encoding*" when the current locale is UTF-8. However, that does not seem to be the case with the current implementation of the UCRT.
- For writing the wide char, `#include <io.h>` and `<fcntl.h>`, and replace the `fprintf` line with:

  ```
  _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
  wprintf(L"%04x '%wc' %d %d\n", wc, wc, ferror(file), feof(file));
  ```

  The [`printf` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-160#remarks) states:

  > *wprintf is a wide-character version of printf; format is a wide-character string. wprintf and printf behave identically if the stream is opened in ANSI mode*. ***printf does not currently support output into a UNICODE stream***.